# How to pass multiple Model in a View and How to Configure Controller to Handle Multiple FORM from a Single View Page in ASP.NET core MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanna implement Login and Registration on the Same page and Both is having there own Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a view model that encapsulates both of these models. For example:

```
public class CombinedLoginRegisterViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel Login { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel Register { get; set; }
}
```

In your view, ensure that the fields for each are contained inside separate form tags. This is the most important part. In this way, you will only ever submit the fields for one of these sub-models, and not the other. The other sub-model then, will be set to null, which is what allows everything else to work. Also, be careful of name prefix for your form fields. As long as you use the `*For` family of helpers, you should be fine, but if you're using partials and such you may need to take more care. Long and short, your should end up with HTML inputs with name attributes like `Login.Username` and `Login.Password`, rather than just `Username`/`Password`.

On post, only one or the other, then, will be not null, depending on which set of fields got posted. Therefore, you can test in your post action and branch accordingly:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (model.Login != null)
    {
        // do login
    }
    else if (model.Register != null)
    {
        // do register
    }
}
```

It's important to note that validation only occurs on class instances that are not null. As a result, you can still require properties and such, and `ModelState.IsValid` will only be false, if the posted sub-model set of fields is invalid. Since the other will be null, no validation rules will be applied on that.

**Update**

Here's some sample code to go along with my comment to @TrevorWard below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginRegister(CombinedLoginRegisterViewModel model)
{
    // This check is basically just to confirm all required fields
    // were entered.
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Login != null)
        {
            DoLogin(model.Login);
        }
        else if (model.Register != null)
        {
            DoRegister(model.Register);
        }

        // Second check here allows you to add ModelState errors in the
        // DoLogin/DoRegister method to bypass the redirect and redisplay
        // the form.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }
    }

    // Redisplay view on validation errors
    return View(model);
}

protected void DoLogin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    // do login
}

protected void DoRegister(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    // do register
}
```

Comment: Using the combined ViewModel is necessary but each form should be posting to a different controller action

Comment: @TrevorWard: Not necessary. As I said, as long as you keep each in a separate form tag, you can branch in a single post action depending on which is non-null. Likely, the desire to post to different controller actions comes from a purist viewpoint, not wanting one action to be handling both situations. However, unless you post to the same action, you cannot redisplay the original combined form view with errors if ModelState is not valid. If you're truly concerned about too much going on the action, you can factor out the actual login/register handling code into private/protected methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `View Components`. But i am not sure it is best implementation.

Simple implementation is like below:

HomeController

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return View("Index", model);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return View("Index", model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Index View

```
@Component.Invoke("LoginComponent")
@Component.Invoke("RegisterComponent")
```

LoginComponent

```
 [ViewComponent(Name = "LoginComponent")]
 public class LoginComponent : ViewComponent
 {
     public LoginComponent()
     {

     }
     public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
     {
            return View(new LoginModel());
     }
 }
```

LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string L_UserName { get; set; }

    public string L_Password { get; set; }
}
```

Finally Login Component View

```
@model LoginModel
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <input asp-for="L_UserName" />
    <input asp-for="L_Password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having the forms submit their values to different controller methods. You cannot pass multiple models to the view, but you can combine those models into a single view model. As long as the html elements' name tags correspond to the properties of the model expected by the controller methods, and the values are of the right types, the model binder will work things out for you.